# Magento configuration - populating field when using frontend_model

Tags: configuration, magento

I have specified a frontend_model in system.xml for an entry field. I did this because I wanted to make a field read-only. There may have been a more straightforward way to achieve that, but that's where I am at the moment. The thing is I cannot get the field to display the data it should.

I have a button that when pressed, populates the read-only field. That works fine. But when I hit 'Save Config', the data disappears from the field. The reason it disappears is because I can't find out what I should set the field's value to. Below tries using the getEscapedValue() method of Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract, but it returns nothing. And as usual with Magento, there is no documentation to speak of.

```
class Mypackage_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_DisabledText extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate('mypackage/system/config/disabled_text.phtml');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $originalData = $element->getOriginalData();
        $this->addData(array(
            'my_value' => $element->getEscapedValue(),
            'html_id' => $element->getHtmlId(),
        ));
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

disabled_text.phtml contains the following:

```
<input id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getMyValue(); ?>" class=" input-text" type="text" disabled/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you have forgotten to specify name for your input element, so when you press save config button, your field is not sent to controller that saves the configuration.

Comment: Hi - I tried adding name attribute to the html <input> element, but that made no difference. Even if that does result in the controller saving the configuration, surely me setting the html <input> value attribute to "<?php echo $this->getMyValue() ?>", when getMyValue() returns nothing (because $element->getEscapedValue() returned nothing) would reset the value to blank anyway?

Answer (score 6):

This is one of those places where you  need to look at how Magento itself is doing something similar to what you want to do.  If you look at the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field` class's `_getElementHtml`

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{        
    return $element->getElementHtml();
}
```

you can see that this method accepts a form element that's already been instantiated (based on what's in system.xml), and then this element renders itself with `getElementHtml`.  That means when Magento needs to render (and, in turn, get the value) it does so in from the element object.  Some crude debugging will let us know where `getElementHtml` can be located

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{        
    var_dump(get_class($element));    
    return $element->getElementHtml();
}
```

Something like `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text` will be dumped to the screen.  In turn, this class inherits form `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract`, which contains the following definition

```
public function getElementHtml()
{
    $html = '<input id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" name="'.$this->getName()
         .'" value="'.$this->getEscapedValue().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).'/>'."\n";
    $html.= $this->getAfterElementHtml();
    return $html;
}
```

So, when **Magento** wants to get the value for a system config field, it uses the above PHP code to render the input.  So, if you want to do the same in your template, I'd try something like this

Up in the class, assign a block property with the entire element.  This is actually more efficient that plucking values out of the elements, since all PHP needs to store is an object reference.

```
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $this->setMyElement($element);
    return $this->_toHtml();
}
```

Then, in the template, copy the code from magento's rendering, replacing the "$this" keyword with your saved element

```
<?php $_element = $this->getMyElement(); ?>
<!-- check the quoting/escaping on this html/php, I didn't actually run it, but the concept is sound -->
<input  disabled="disabled" id="<?php echo $_element->getHtmlId();?>" name="<?php echo $_element->getName();?>" 
        value="<?php echo $_element->getEscapedValue();?>" 
        <?php echo $_element->serialize($_element->getHtmlAttributes());?>
/>
<?php echo $_element->getAfterElementHtml(); ?>
```

When you're working with Magento, try to think like a Magento developer.  Instead of "I need to figure out how to make it do X", think "I need to add this feature to the store in the same way the rest of my teammates have".  Then look how the core team did it, and copy their implementation, changing as little as you need to.

It does get easier the more you work with the system!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Alan. I think what you suggest is no different to my code though (it behaves the same too - i.e. when Save Config the value disappears from the field).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Alan. I think what you suggest is no different to my code though (it behaves the same too - i.e. when Save Config the value disappears from the field). Maybe it is something to do with how I populate the field? The field is disabled and is populated using javascript invoked by clicking a button elsewhere on my config form: $('mymodule_controlinformation_myfield')=somevar; When I click the button, the field is populated correctly. But then disappears after the Save Config. Not sure if relevant, but all other fields have [STORE VIEW] against them, except my field.

Comment: If you're sure that your code is doing the same thing as Magento's core code, break the problem apart further.  1. Is your value being saved in the database when click click save.  2. Is your value being pull out correctly from the database when the page loads 3. Is your value being output correctly when the form renders.  One of those three things isn't happening correctly.  Dig into each one, and once you find out which one isn't being performed correctly, you'll have your problem.  It's too detailed a problem to answer in one forum post.

Comment: It turns out the reason for the behaviour that I was seeing is because Magento skips over disabled fields when saving the configuration. I changed the field to readonly and the value was saved. I don't suppose you have any idea why my field does not have [STORE VIEW] next to it? And if it's a problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the name of the extension/module this element belongs to as seen in the system.xml file if you look at sections and then module="[extensionname]"? Sorry idk if I'm saying it right...

Comment: @banning Sounds like a new question for here, or for the Magento Stack Exchange site http://magento.stackexchange.com